# Docker issue with python script in Azure logic app not connecting to current Azure blob storage

Tags: python-3.x, docker, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage

Every day, an Excel file is automatically uploaded to my Azure blob storage account. I have a Python script that reads the Excel file, extracts the necessary information, and saves the output as a new blob in the Azure storage account. I set up a Docker container that runs this Python script. It works correctly when run locally.

I pushed the Docker image to the Azure container registry and tried to set up an Azure logic app that starts a container with this Docker image every day at the same time. It runs, however, it does not seem to be working with the most updated version of my Azure storage account.

For example, I pushed an updated version of the Docker image last night. A new Excel file was added to the Azure storage account this morning and the logic app ran one hour later. The container with the Docker image, however, only found the files that were present in Azure storage account yesterday (so it was missing the most recent file, which is the one I needed analyzed).

I confirmed that the issue is not with the logic app as I added a step in the logic app to list the files in the Azure storage account, and this list included the most recent file.

UPDATE: I have confirmed that I am accessing the correct version of the environment variables. The issue remains: the Docker container seems to access Azure blob storage as it was at the time I most recently pushed the Docker image to the container registry. My current work around is to push the same image to the registry everyday, but this is annoying.

ANOTHER UPDATE: Here is the code to get the most recent blob (an Excel file). The date is always contained in the name of the blob. In theory, it finds the blob with the most recent date:

```
blobs = blob_service.list_blobs(container_name=os.environ.get("CONTAINERNAME"))

blobstring = blob_service.get_blob_to_text(os.environ.get("CONTAINERNAME"),
                                           backup_csv).content
current_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(blobstring))

add_n = 1

blob_string = re.compile("sales.xls")
for b in blobs:
    if blob_string.search(b.name):
        dt = b.name[14:24]
        dt = datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        date_list.append(dt)

today = max(date_list)
print(today)
```

However, the blobs don't seem to update. It returns the most recent blob as of the date that I last pushed the image to the registry.

I also checked `print(date.today())` in the same script and this works as expected (it prints the current date).

Comment: How are you figuring out which existing files you have?

Comment: Updated the question with Python code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that I just needed to make all of the variables in my .env file and add them as environment variables with appropriate values in the 'containers environment' section of the image above. This https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-environment-variables was a helpful resource.

ALSO the container group needs to be deleted as the last action in the logic app. I named the wrong container group, so when the logic app ran each day, it used the cached version of the container.